# Resource Bundle - make reference to other strings?

Tags: java, jsf, properties, resourcebundle

can I make references within a resource bundle?

eg:

```
label.name=John
label.surname=Doe

label.fullname=<label.name> <label.surename>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
label.fullname = {0} {1}
```

and while rendering it

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.label.fullname}">
  <f:param value="#{bundle.label.name}"/>
  <f:param value="#{bundle.label.surname}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

or you could try this out

```
CONST_1 = name
CONST_2 = surname
fullname = {CONST_1}  {CONST_2}
```

from [here](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Java/archives/0612/mair/index.html)

Comment: This is my present workaround, yes. But when I use the resource inside a backing bean class, I have to manually build the String s = ResourceBundle()... + " " + ResourceBundle()... + " " +... and so on. If I want to use a combination of some strings. But that's really ugly, I thought I could make a direct reference inside the resource bundle to other strings, and then just use this single string.

Comment: hmm that does not work! just copypasted the few lines and referenced to fullname, but is just prints out: {CONST_1} {CONST_2} not replacing anything.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this post, I figured I would share a recent find.

Using commons-configuration from Apache Commons, you can reference other properties in the same file as follows:

```
foo=somevalue
foo.bar=${foo}
```